# issue with ivar

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I'm subclassing a UIToolbar because I'm gonna reuse it all over my app. The UIToolbar uses a delegate protocol:

```
//
// UIToolbarCustom.h
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol UIToolbarCustomDelegate

@required
- (void)tab:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender;
- (void)ok:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender;

@end

@interface UIToolbarCustom : UIToolbar {

    id <UIToolbarCustomDelegate> delegate;

}

@property (strong, nonatomic) id delegate;

@end
```

The standford iOS development course teacher recommends to explicit declare all the ivars prefixing it with a underscore, like:

```
@implementation UIToolbarCustom

@synthesize delegate = _delegate;

@end
```

But, in this specify scenarion it gives me a error:

```
error: property 'delegate' attempting to use ivar '_delegate'...
```

The code works just fine if I use:

```
 @synthesize delegate = __delegate; or
 @synthesize delegate;
```

What is going on here? Is there a private instance variable in the UIToolbar class named _delegate?

**UPDATE**

Thank all you guys for all the clarifications and protips, I'm learning a lot. Turns out that I'm new to iOS development (this is my first app second version, so I'm trying to do it right =p). Following the tips I came out with this new header file:

```
//
// Toolbar.h
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol ToolbarDelegate

@required
- (void)tab:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender;
- (void)ok:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender;

@end

@interface Toolbar : UIToolbar

@property (strong, nonatomic) id delegate;

@end
```

Notes:

1. The class prefix was removed.
2. The delegate declaration was removed (I'm using a ios delegate tutorial code, but the code sample uses a older xcode version, where the declaration is needed).
3. The synthesize was removed, I also didn't knew that we don't need synthesize our properties anymore.

PS: Obviously the code does not work, because the ivar problem. I'm gonna change its names, so I don't need to synthesize it, not sure about what name to use anyways...

Comment: Tip: When you subclass a UIKit class, change the prefix from UI to whatever prefix you use for your own classes. That makes it easier to spot your own classes immediately, makes naming things a little more natural (e.g. you can use *LLToolbar* instead of *UIToolbarCustom*), and (most important) it avoids the possibility that Apple will add a class with the same name. Avoiding name conflicts is the main reason that prefixes are used in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is going on here? Is there a private instance variable in the UIToolbar class named _delegate?

Yes, that's exactly the problem. You need to come up with a different name for your instance variable. `__delegate` will work, or you could prefix the name with a 3 letter prefix (see last paragraph).

Do note that you've declared your ivar as `delegate`, then in the synthesize statement told the compiler to use `_delegate`. Effectively that means that your `delegate` ivar isn't being used at all. In any case, if you're writing for iOS (as opposed to 32-bit Mac), like you are, you don't need the explicit instance variable declaration in your subclass's @interface section, because the compiler will automatically create it for you.

Finally, it's bad form to name your own subclass something that begins with 'UI', since the UI prefix is reserved for classes that are part of UIKit. You should use your own 3 letter prefix instead, or else no prefix at all. The problem is that a future version of UIKit could conceivably include a class called "UIToolbarCustom", and your subclass would collide with it.

Comment: This isn't entirely correct... he's colliding with his own previous declaration, not a private/internal Apple ivar (which wouldn't collide because they use a different ivar convention).

Comment: Again, that's not true. And, if you don't believe that you can collide with a private/internal Apple ivar, try subclassing UIViewController and creating a property called `popoverController` with its backing ivar named `_popoverController`. You'll get the exact error the OP describes. As you can see by looking at UIToolbar.h, UIToolbar indeed has its own instance variable called `_delegate`.

Comment: It's not that I don't believe that you cannot collide, obviously that's possible. My understanding, and what I was taught, was that the preceding _underscore convention was introduced for 3rd party developers specifically so they could avoid collision with internal ivars. Hence my surprise in this case...

Comment: If you look around at the UIKit class headers, you'll actually see that most of them include underscore prefixed ivar names. My understanding for the recommendation, and the reason I do it, is as a safety against direct ivar access when you mean to access the property via the accessor methods. e.g. `name = @"Bob";` will give you an error, reminding/forcing you to use `self.name = @"Bob";` Of course, so many Objective-C programmers use direct ivar access all over anyway. With ARC, it's not nearly as big of a deal, of course. Anyway, that's a completely separate discussion...

Answer (score 1):

Since last year, when Xcode 4.3 came out, you don't need to synthesize your properties. It is done for you by the compiler (an ivar is generated, and a leading underscore is added to its name). This means that you also don't need to declare an ivar. If you do, be sure to name it something other than `_delegate`.

So, all you really need is this line:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) id<UIToolbarCustomDelegate> delegate;
```

**UPDATE**: please see the [Andrew Madsen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14204661/839965) for the full story. Turns out UIToolbar has its own ivar named `_delegate`. Who knew!

Comment: This is true, but the compiler will synthesize an instance variable called `_delegate` and it will collide just the same.

Comment: True. But you don't need to declare this ivar, I think. I updated my answer to explain this a little better.

Comment: As a solution this works, but it doesn't fully explain to the asker why his code didn't work - the reason being, he was declaring an ivar and a property with the same name.

Comment: @BlackRider, you're correct that you don't need to explicitly declare the instance variable. But that has nothing to do with a subclass's ivar name colliding with one of the superclasses ivars. If you leave the ivar declaration out, `@synthesize delegate = _delegate;` will still create an ivar called `_delegate` (as it's actually doing in the OP's posted code, since his declared ivar is named `delegate`), and it will *still* collide with the superclass's ivar named the same thing.

Comment: @AndrewMadsen: just saw your answer and it makes a lot of sense. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @AndrewMadsen Out of curiosity how are you so sure of this collision - from personal experience? Do you know for a fact that UIToolbar has an _delegate ivar? I've certainly never seen it, and no delegate protocol is declared for this class...

Comment: @isaac, I haven't actually tried subclassing UIToolbar myself. However, if you open UIToolbar.h, you'll see that the very first instance variable is indeed `id _delegate`!

Comment: Thank you anyways, the real problem is the UIToolbar private instance variable named _delegate, but I learned something very usefull with you.